# Find the Taylor series expansion of $\csc x$ in ascending powers of $(x-\frac{\pi}{4})$ up to and including the term in $(x-\frac{\pi}{4})^3$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find the Taylor series expansion of $\csc x$ in ascending powers of $(x-\dfrac{\pi}{4})$ up to and including the term in $(x-\dfrac{\pi}{4})^3$

I've been discussing this with my friend and we're both a bit confused. Our professor didn't explain it very well. I can't explain the problem we're having too well, but we're basically confused about what x is, and what a is, and how to do this question - we're wondering if the answer in the back of the book is wrong:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\csc(\frac{\pi}{4})=\sqrt{2} \text{ since } \sin(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{d}{dx} \csc(x)=- \csc(x) \cot(x) \\ \text{ and } - \csc(x) \cot(x) \text{ evaluated at } \\ x=\frac{\pi}{4} \text{ gives } - \sqrt{2} \cdot 1=-\sqrt{2} \text{ so far it seems the answer is right } \\ \text{ you have } a=\frac{\pi}{4} \text{ and } f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2}(x-a)^2+\frac{f'''(a)}{3 \cdot 2 }(x-a)^3+\cdots \text{ where } f(x)=\csc(x)$